# Shall i implement the 301-redirection method to my site inner pages?

Tags: http-status-code-301

Actually I am working in a one url, now my client told me to change the domain name, so I have planned to do 301-redirection for my home page in a new domain. But i have worked for both home and inner pages on my previous site. Is it recommended to do the 301-redirection for my inner pages too, please help me....

Answer (score 0):

There should be an option in your hosting panel to manage `redirects` you can then redirect the whole domain, and send it to the new domain. I hope this helps.

Comment: That would mean if you want to an inner page on old domain it would send to the new domain. A single page redirect would only affect the one page.

Comment: Thanks Bigwater for your useful tips

Comment: No worries, please click the tick next to my answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is recommended that you redirect all of your existing pages/urls to new domain. This will retain your SEO ranking and also the customers who've bookmarked earlier domain.

However, instead of doing a redirect of each individual URL, you could use the power of .htaccess file and put below code to catch all the request coming for old domain (lets say example.com) and redirect them to corresponding pages on new domain (lets say example.org)
You could use something like below

```
# Detect if the request was raised for old domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer Mr.Rashmirathi, Now am clear with this concept, still i have one more doubts too, can i get all seo values to my new domain including my previous inner pages values too.

Comment: Yes, when presented with 301, Google (and other Search engines) will detect that the page is permanently moved to the new domain. Search engines interpret this to mean that not only has the page changed location, but that the content—or an updated version of it—can be found at the new URL. The engines will carry any link weighting from the original page to the new URL. You could found more details at https://seo-hacker.com/301-302-redirect-affect-seo/